# How to display HTML tags within h:outputText tags?

Tags: html, jsf

I have a scenario in which there is a JSF tags as

```
<h:outputText escape="false" value="#{someBean.someValue}" />
```

someValue gets its value from database through SQL query. The output of following SQL query gets stored in someValue property of my bean class someBean.

```
SELECT Wm_Concat(DISTINCT  CASE WHEN sv.rmvd = 0 THEN   ' '||sv.CMPNION_CD  ELSE '&lt;span style=&quot;color:blue;font-weight:bold;&quot;&gt;' || ' '||sv.CMPNION_CD|| '&lt;/span&gt;' END) FROM SOMEDATABASE
```

I am getting output as

```
<span style="color:blue;font-weight:bold;"> 8000778</span>,<span style="color:blue;font-weight:bold;"> 8000780</span>
```

However, I want the HTML span tag to be effective on 8000778 and 8000780. How can I achieve this?

Comment: how is this JSF related? looks like it displays what you put in the bean. And what does _" I want the HTML span tag to be effective on 8000778 and 8000780"_ mean? You want just 1 span span around both numbers? Then fix your query

Comment: @Kukeltje : The query fetches two values 8000778 and 8000780 and SQL query is designed to have span tag around both the values. That is why I mentioned that instead of displaying the entire HTML content as it-is on output page, I want the HTML span styling to be effective on values fetched by query.

Comment: @4castle: I don't completely understand what you mean. If you're asking me to have styling outside the value attribute then it's not possible in my case because styling is conditional. What I mean is if query is returning 5 values 100, 101, 102, 103, 104 then on the basis of a condition (CASE WHEN sv.rmvd = 0 ), HTML styling should be applicable to only few values. For example, only 100 and 102 should be bold and blue. rest numbers normal.

Comment: @4castle: not true, you can... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10517200/houtputtext-prints-html-as-is-instead-of-actual-html

Comment: Awesome! Problem resolved. I will write my solution here for people who might face similar issue. Initially my someValue in h:outputText was getting  '&lt;span style=&quot;color:blue;font-weight:bold;&quot;&gt;' || ' '||sv.CMPNION_CD|| '&lt;/span&gt;' and there was escape="false" in h:outputText. I changed the SQL query. Now it returns - '<html><span style=\"color:red; font-weight:bold;\">' || ' '||sv.CMPNION_CD|| '</span></html>'    ... Added <html> tag.. and since escape is already "false", I unescaped in my query. And it works..!!

Comment: No need to, it is already marked as a duplicate